# Edit Appendices Layout (name, header, name in ToC)

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I tried to find an answer on this forum, but the solutions I found didn't work for me.
I need to change three things in the Appendices:

- the title shown at the beginning (between the end of the main matter of my thesis and the first appendix), from "Appendices" to "Appendici"
- the header in the appendix section, which now is - for example, for the Appendix A - "Chapter A: AppendixName", to "Appendice A: AppendixName" (I'm interested in this problem above all)
- the title in the Table of Contents, from "Appendices" to "Appendici"

Can you help me?

I'm using the `book` document class and `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}`.

Edit: I don't know if it is a useful information, but after `\begin{appendices}` I have

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\centering\Large\scshape}{Appendice \thechapter \\ \textcolor{gray75}{ \rule[2pt]{1.5cm}{2pt}\vspace{0.5mm} \\}}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
```

(the same used to set the title format for chapters) and I'm using also

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\ifnum\value{chapter}>0
\markboth{Capitolo \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
\else
\markboth{#1}{}%
\fi}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE for us to better see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think given that you are using the `appendix`pacakge, you only need to reset the proper names for the appendix

- For the ToC name: `\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendici}`
- For the page preceding the appendices: `\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendici}`
- For the actual appendix: `\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendice}`

And to put 'Apendice' in front of the appedix letter:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\backmatter{
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
            \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
            \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
\makeatother
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \markboth{Capitolo \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
    \else
    \markboth{#1}{}%
    \fi}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\backmatter{
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
            \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
            \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendici}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendici}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendice}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Some chapter}
    \lipsum[1-4]

    \begin{appendices}
        \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\centering\Large\scshape}{Appendice \thechapter \\ \textcolor{gray}{ \rule[2pt]{1.5cm}{2pt}\vspace{0.5mm} \\}}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
        \chapter{Some Appendix}
        \lipsum[5-9]
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]